# Accesing the microphone in Android to do my own recording

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

I would like to be able to access the microphone in Android and write the data/buffer from it directly (live).  Is there any library for that?

So for instance right now I have the code below, but that's a closed system.  i.e. The data is recorded before I can get to it.  Was hoping someone knew of a library out there where I could do it myself, or hook the microphone, etc.

Many thanks.

```
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mRecorder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

outside the application block actually solved it!

```
</application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```